# Querying Assets in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: rest, api, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Is it possible to query all the transactions that contain a specific asset in Hyperledger Composer?.

Is it also possible to query the transaction history by identifier?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should use the Historian if you want to search through transactions.

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/historian.html

Comment: see also answer #2 here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036099/how-to-show-transaction-input-data-in-a-hyperledger-composer-query

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below JSON into your .qry file and try to access it from logic file.

query transactionHistory{
description: "It will return all transaction history record."
statement: SELECT org.acme.sample.NAME_OF_TRANSACTION_CLASS 
}