# How to query the details of a Hyperledger Fabric Transaction

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-explorer

If you deploy your network on the composer playground you can access the "all Transactions"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFPLo.png)

which I assume same as implementing

"SELECT org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord"

However in the playground there is a button "View Record"

that provides the transaction details :

```
{
 "$class": "org.ACME.OwnershipChange",
 "PreviousOwner": "WHF_123",
 "NewOwner": "HFS_456",
 "debtID": "123123126",
 "transactionId": "4e04116f-5788-48ac-9930-e0bf3beb74e3",
 "timestamp": "2019-03-20T19:53:42.796Z"
}
```

When trying to implement a Historian Record query via Composer REST I get all the details of the Record but not the details of the transaction as in the mentioned above "View Record"

```
{
    "$class": "org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord",
    "transactionId": "2c80fd8b89cef32fb9dff6864d76b9fecd2194cd447266161fc9d1fb1a32aed9",
    "transactionType": "org.ACME.OwnershipChange",
    "transactionInvoked": "resource:org.ACME.OwnershipChange#2c80fd8b89cef32fb9dff6864d76b9fecd2194cd447266161fc9d1fb1a32aed9",
    "participantInvoking": "resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin#admin",
    "identityUsed": "resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.Identity#d258882fc3c452601433a729958ba3c592bd31e95fc43fbf493f5be3dc566dd1",
    "eventsEmitted": [],
    "transactionTimestamp": "2019-03-21T20:05:49.504Z"
  },
```

How do I query the view record details ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in this thread.

Instead of Querying `SELECT org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord`
try querying  `SELECT org.ACME.OwnershipChange`

[How to show transaction input data in a Hyperledger Composer query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036099/how-to-show-transaction-input-data-in-a-hyperledger-composer-query)